# How can I scrape content on the next page of the posts I have already scraped?

Tags: python, html, django, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have been programming for almost a year, I am a novice. I am working on a django web app that scrapes posts and then follows the hyper link of each post and scrapes the body text so I can store it. I can scrape the posts fine, but following the link of each post and scraping it is not working out how I wanted. I tried a configuration that I thought would work but it kept giving me the error message

```
'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'a'
```

This is my code

```
def scrape_and_store_vlad():
    url_two = 'http://www.example.com'
    html = requests.get(url_two, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html5lib')
    titles = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'entry-pos-1'})

    comments_url = url_two + titles.a.get('href') <-----problem here line 69
    comments_html = requests.get(comments_url, headers=headers)
    comments_soup = BeautifulSoup(comments_html.text, "html5lib")
    comments = comments_soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'article-body'})


    entries = [{'href': url_two + div.a.get('href'),
                'src': url_two + div.a.img.get('data-original'),
                'text': div.find('p', 'entry-title').text,
                'comments': comments.text
                } for div in titles][:6]

    titles_two = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'entry-pos-2'})
    entries_two = [{'href': url_two + div.a.get('href'),
                'src': url_two + div.a.img.get('data-original'),
                'text': div.find('p', 'entry-title').text,
                'comments': comments.text
                } for div in titles_two][:6]

    merged__entries = entries + entries_two

    return merged__entries
```

this was my code prior to modifying it to scrape the following page of each post

```
def scrape_and_store_vlad():
    url_two = 'http://www.example.com'
    html = requests.get(url_two, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html5lib')
    titles = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'entry-pos-1'})
    entries = [{'href': url_two + div.a.get('href'),
                'src': url_two + div.a.img.get('data-original'),
                'text': div.find('p', 'entry-title').text,
                } for div in titles][:6]

    titles_two = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'entry-pos-2'})
    entries_two = [{'href': url_two + div.a.get('href'),
                'src': url_two + div.a.img.get('data-original'),
                'text': div.find('p', 'entry-title').text,
                } for div in titles_two][:6]

    merged__entries = entries + entries_two

    return merged__entries
```

and this is the basic html tree of the next page whose content I want to scrape

```
body
  div id=wrapper
    div class=container
      div class=body-clearfix
        div class=column-main
          article
            div class=article-body
```

how can I correct my syntax so this will work the way I want it to?

Comment: A list/ResultSet does not have an anchor tag, paste the full traceback to show the exact line

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I edited my code above to show where django says where my issue is coming from

Answer (score 0):

You need to extract the hrefs from the titles inside `list/ResultSet`, `find_all` returns a list from 0-n matches:

```
comments_urls =  [ url_two + d.a[href] for d in titles]
```

That would give you a list of urls which you would need to iterate over. I would also recommend using *urlparse*:

```
from urlparse import urljoin

comments_urls =  [urljoin(url_two, d.a['href']) for a in titles]
```

Then:

```
for url in comment_urls:
    # rest of scraping logic
```

To make sure we only get anchors that have hrefs, use a css select:

```
titles = soup.select('div.entry-pos-1 a[href]')
```

Also if you want a the first six divs from `find_all('div', {'class': 'entry-pos-2'}`, you can set a limit instead of slicing in your comprehension:

```
titles_two = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'entry-pos-2'}, limit=6)
```

Comment: I just tried what you suggested and got this error message "Can't convert 'NoneType' object to str implicitly"

Comment: @binary_stax, that is because not all the `div.entry-pos-1` tags have an anchor tag with a href, use the css select I added

Comment: I get this error message Invalid URL '[]': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://[]?

Comment: That is not possible with any code I have provided, what line is causing the error?

Comment: @PadraicCinningham     '/python3.5/site-packages/requests/models.py in prepare_url, line 355'

Comment: that's where Django is telling me where the error is. Other than that I don't know. That's what I'm hoping I can get some guidance in.

Comment: from the error it is saying you are passing an empty list  as a str i.e `"[]"`, I have no idea how that is possible bar it is happening in your djano app itself where you are passing an empty list to some template. What are you doing with merged_entries?

Comment: but how can that be if when i'm scraping the page without going to the next all the links are there?